# Get table details whose name is there in other table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one main table

```
MainTable ( ID, Name )
```

The Name column contains the name of other table there in database.

I want a query to fetch all the information from the table whose name is referenced in Name column of MainTable.

Eg:
Main Table

```
ID 1, Name A
ID 2, Name B
```

Table A

```
~~~~ Values~~~~
```

Table B

```
~~~~ Values~~~~
```

When query for 1 is sent then all values for A should come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with SQLite, AFAIK. Work this dynamic SQL out at an application level.

Comment: What will be the query for the same in oracle..??

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL query

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

declare @table nvarchar(max)

declare  @no int;

set @no =1 (pass it dynamically)

set @table ='select tablename from table1 where id = '+@no+''

exec(@table)

set @sql = 'select * from '+@table+''

exec (@sql)

Hope this works.

please give us the real values so that we can make it work :)

Comment: could you provide the database to which the query should be run?

Comment: MainT (ID, Name) {(1,A),(2,B),(3,C)}

A(ID,Values)
B(ID,Values)
C(ID,Values)

When query says id 1 in MainT, Table A all values should come